# Indicator functions are independent

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I'm trying to prove that :

> Suppose $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ is a probability space and $A,B \in \mathcal{F}$.
> Then $1_A, 1_B$ are independent random variables if and only if $A, B$ are independent events.

Using the following definition of independence of random variables (Measure Integration and Real Analysis, Axler 2020):

> Two random variables $X, Y$ are called independent if ${X \in U}$ and ${Y \in V}$ are independent events for all Borel sets $U, V \in \mathbb{R}$

But I can't connect the two probabilities $P(A)$ and $P(1_A \in U)$ with $U$ is a Borel set in $\mathbb{R}$.

Could you please give some suggestions on this proof ?

Answer (score 2):

$\implies$

$$
\mathbb{P}(\{\mathbf{1_A}=1\}\cap\{\mathbf{1_B}=1\})
=\mathbb{P}(\{\mathbf{1_{A\cap B}}=1\})
=\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)
$$

By definition of independent r.v, those corresponding signed events need to be independent.

$$\mathbb{P}(\{\mathbf{1_A}=1\}\cap\{\mathbf{1_B}=1\})=\mathbb{P}(\{\mathbf{1_A}=1\})\times\mathbb{P}(\{\mathbf{1_B}=1\})=\mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B)$$

So that we obtained  $\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)=\mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B)$

$\impliedby$

Given $$\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)=\mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B)\\
\mathbb{P}(\{\mathbf{1_{A\cap B}}=1\})=\mathbb{P}(\{\mathbf{1_A}=1\})\mathbb{P}(\{\mathbf{1_B}=1\})\\
\mathbb{P}(\{\mathbf{1_A1_B}=1\})=\mathbb{P}(\{\mathbf{1_A}=1\})\mathbb{P}(\{\mathbf{1_B}=1\})\\
\mathbb{P}(\{\mathbf{1_{A}}=1\}\cap\{\mathbf{1_B}=1\})=\mathbb{P}(\{\mathbf{1_A=1}\})\mathbb{P}(\{\mathbf{1_B=1}\})
$$

so that $\mathbf{1_A}$ and $\mathbf{1_B}$ are independent r.v

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $P(1_A =1)=P(A), P(1_A =0)=P(A^c)$.

Same goes for $B$.

Then $P(1_A=1,1_B=1)= P(A \cap B)=P(A)P(B) = P(1_A=1)P(1_B=1)$ iff $A$ and $B$ are independent.

We treated the case when $1_A=1$ and $1_B=1$. There are three more cases to treat. Once you treat those, you will have showed that the mass function of the vector $(1_A,1_B)$ factorises, which implies that your definition of independence is satisfied for Borel sets of the form $]-\infty,x]$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$. But those sets generate the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Could you please explain the term "the mass function of the vector $(1_A, 1_B)$ factorises" ? (i.e. what is the mass function of a vector and what does "factorises" mean). Thank you very much!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)#For_real_valued_random_variables